# How do you check if a PHP object is a MongoDate object?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodate

Is there a function like MongoId::isValid($id)? How do you determine if an object is a MongoDate object? Check if $mongoDateObject->sec isset()?

Comment: [instanceof](http://us2.php.net/instanceof)

Comment: Wow, I learned about instanceof, is_a, and get_class today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `if (is_a($mongoDateObject, 'MongoDate')) {...}`
2. `if (get_class($mongoDateObject) == 'MongoDate')) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($mongoDateObject instanceof MongoDate) {...}
```